# Collapsed Bootstrap navbar button won't work on pages that aren't located in the root folder

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with opening collapsed menus for pages that aren't located in the root folder. The navbar is part of the masterpage and it works fine on all pages located in the root folder but when the page is located in a subfolder the button to open the collapsed menu won't respond (For instance: For ./Default the menu appears and when collapsed the button drops down a menu as intended, but for ./Admin/Default the menu is visible but onced it is collapsed the button is unresponsive). Being that it's part of the code for the masterpage, I don't understand why this is only occuring on certain pages.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits`="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">             
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/Default.aspx" class="navbar-brand">SLPL Automated Circulation System</a>
            </div>
        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <asp:Menu ID="menu_Master" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="vertical" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav navbar-nav" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="active" DynamicMenuStyle-CssClass="dropdown dropdown-menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"></asp:Menu>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   


    <div class="container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //to fix collapse mode width issue
            $(".nav li,.nav li a,.nav li ul").removeAttr('style');

            //for dropdown menu
            $(".dropdown-menu").parent().removeClass().addClass('dropdown');
            $(".dropdown>a").removeClass().addClass('dropdown-toggle').append('<b class="caret"></b>').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');

            //remove default click redirect effect           
            $('.dropdown-toggle').attr('onclick', '').off('click');

        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the error that appears when you press F12 and the console appears?

Comment: I guess your path to your `bootstrap.min.js` isn't correct on the subpages. Try using absolute paths. (http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: 'GET http://localhost:54708/Librarian/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)'. I definitely looks to be an issue with it looking for the js file in the wrong folder. I'll try using an absolute path to the bootstrap.min.js as you suggested. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Scott Thompson How You Solve the Problem Can you help me Please ?Since I am facing the same issue